# ASM: how to easily get proper Opcode based on type

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM to generate Java bytecode. I have a need to create a dynamic proxy which can override basically any kind of method with additional post-processing. I am able to do it all, but there is one thing I can't see how to do in a nice way.

The type of the first parameter to the method I am overriding can be anything, so I can't use `ALOAD` in the ASM code, but I might need to use `ILOAD`, `LLOAD`, `FLOAD` etc.
My question: based on parameter type I want to load, is there a way to easily know which LOAD instruction opcode is valid, so I don't have to do something like:

```
if (parameterType == int.class)
    mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 1);
else if 
    ...
else 
    mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
```

Comment: What kind of code are you trying to generate? Is it just loading the arguments and immediately calling another function?

Comment: In fact, in this phase, that is correct. Calling another method, and then some callback execution after the call (in the same method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `parameterType` is of type `Class` OR  of type `String` containing a type descriptor (like `"I"` or `"Ljava/lang/String;"`), then:

```
import org.objectweb.asm.Type;

...

Type parameterAsmType = Type.getType(parameterType);
int opcode = parameterAsmType.getOpcode(Opcodes.ILOAD);
mv.visitVarInsn(opcode, 1);
```

Similarly for other opcodes. See the [`Type.getOpcode()` javadoc](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getOpcode-int-) for details.

Comment: In general, you might want to consider using the GeneratorAdapter class provided with ASM - it contains a lot of nice helper methods, including a method doing what I showed above..